# Protractor - What expected condition to use here?

Tags: android, html, ionic-framework, automation, protractor

I have 3 tabs, that I need to test if they are clicked or not, but I can't seem to find a good expected condition to use. Right now I am using a browser. sleep with higher times, since the tab takes a couple of seconds to load.

The tabs:

[image: Tabs]

Code:

```
let locator = {

  upcomingTabButton : element(by.css('div.toolbar-content.toolbar-content-md ion-segment ion-segment-button:nth-child(1)')),
  pendingTabButton : element(by.css('div.toolbar-content.toolbar-content-md ion-segment ion-segment-button:nth-child(2)')),
  completedTabButton : element(by.css('div.toolbar-content.toolbar-content-md ion-segment ion-segment-button:nth-child(3)')),
  activeTab : element(by.css('ion-segment ion-segment-button.segment-button.segment-activated')),
  upcomingActiveTab: element(by.cssContainingText('ion-segment ion-segment-button.segment-button.segment-activated', 'UPCOMING')),


};


describe('When x tab button is pressed, ', function () {

  it('if x = PENDING tab, then it should be activated', () => {
    browser.sleep(1000);
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(locator.pendingTabButton),5000);
    locator.pendingTabButton.click();
    browser.sleep(10000);
    expect(element(by.css('ion-segment ion-segment-button.segment-button.segment-activated')).getText()).toEqual('PENDING');
  });


  it('if x = UPCOMING tab, then it should be activated', () => {

    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(locator.upcomingTabButton),5000);
    locator.upcomingTabButton.click();
    //browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(locator.upcomingActiveTab),5000);
    browser.sleep(10000);
    expect(element(by.css('ion-segment ion-segment-button.segment-button.segment-activated')).getText()).toEqual('UPCOMING');

  });

  it('if x = COMPLETED tab, then it should be activated', () => {

    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(locator.completedTabButton),5000);
    locator.completedTabButton.click();
    //browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(locator.activeTab),5000);
    browser.sleep(10000);
    expect(element(by.css('ion-segment ion-segment-button.segment-button.segment-activated')).getText()).toEqual('COMPLETED');
  });
});
```

I tried some expected conditions but nothing worked since I need to see when the tab is selected and I didn't found any exp condition like that.

I am using the browser.sleep(10000) 10 seconds, but that's, not a good way to use.

Can anyone help me here?

The tabs content takes like 5/6 seconds to load

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * wait until some element is present
 * 
 */
this.waitElement = function(ElmFinder){
    var i = 0;
    var _retryOnErr = function(err) {
        console.log(' <<< warning: wait retrying iteration: ' + i + ' >>> ');
        browser.sleep(500);
        return false;
    };

    browser.wait(function() {
        i++;
        return ElmFinder.isDisplayed().then(function(present) {
            if (present) {
                return true;
            } else {
                console.log("element is not present");
                return _retryOnErr();
            }
        }, _retryOnErr);
    }, 120*1000, 'Error waiting for element present: ').
    then(function(waitRetValue) {
        return waitRetValue; // usually just `true`
    }, function(err) {
        throw err + ' after ' + i + ' iterations.';
    });
};
```